# Mvc5 ExternalLoginCallback : "await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()" fails with "sequence contains more than one element"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, owin-middleware

Why do i keep getting this error with external login callback. Here is what am doing.

imports

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
```

My **AccountController.cs** class

```
.    
.
.
.
.
var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
if (loginInfo == null)
{                    
    return RedirectToAction("Login", new { returnUrl = returnUrl});
}
.
.
.
.
```

**My Startup.cs class**

```
.
.
.
app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);


        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
        //
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
.
.
//https://account.live.com/developers/applications/
        //
        microsoftAuthOptions = new MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = "xxxxxxx",
            ClientSecret = "xxxxxxx",
            CallbackPath = new PathString("/callbacks/microsoft"),
            Provider = new MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationProvider()
            {
                OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
                {
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("MicrosoftAccountAccessToken", context.AccessToken));

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        };
        app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(microsoftAuthOptions);

        //
        twitterAuthOptions = new TwitterAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ConsumerKey = "xxxxxxxx",
            ConsumerSecret = "xxxxxxx",
            CallbackPath = new PathString("/callbacks/twitter"),
            Provider = new TwitterAuthenticationProvider()
            {
                OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
                {
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("TwitterAccessToken", context.AccessToken));

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            },
            BackchannelCertificateValidator = new CertificateSubjectKeyIdentifierValidator(new[]
                {
                    "A5EF0B11CEC04103A34A659048B21CE0572D7D47", // VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G2
                    "0D445C165344C1827E1D20AB25F40163D8BE79A5", // VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
                    "7FD365A7C2DDECBBF03009F34339FA02AF333133", // VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
                    "39A55D933676616E73A761DFA16A7E59CDE66FAD", // Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4
                    "5168FF90AF0207753CCCD9656462A212B859723B", //DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server C‎A 
                    "B13EC36903F8BF4701D498261A0802EF63642BC3" //DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA
                })
        };
        app.UseTwitterAuthentication(twitterAuthOptions);

        //Configure Facebook External Login
        facebookAuthOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions() {
            AppId = "xxxxxxxx",
            AppSecret = "xxxxxxxx",
            CallbackPath = new PathString("/callbacks/facebook"),
            Provider = new FacebookAuthProvider()
            {
                OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
                {
                    context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim("FacebookAccessToken", context.AccessToken));

                    foreach (var claim in context.User)
                    {
                        var claimType = string.Format("urn:facebook:{0}", claim.Key);
                        var claimValue = claim.Value.ToString();

                        if (!context.Identity.HasClaim(claimType, claimValue))
                            context.Identity.AddClaim(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(claimType, claimValue, "XmlSchemaString", "Facebook"));
                    }

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        };
        facebookAuthOptions.Scope.Add("email");
        facebookAuthOptions.Scope.Add("user_about_me");
        facebookAuthOptions.Scope.Add("user_photos");
        facebookAuthOptions.Scope.Add("user_location");
 .
 .
 .
 .
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
  [InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element]
   System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +305
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.<AuthenticateAsync>d__8.MoveNext() +213
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   Microsoft.Owin.Security.<GetExternalLoginInfoAsync>d__a.MoveNext() +189
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +28
   com.hwr.Controllers.<ExternalLoginCallback>d__37.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Bourne Koloh\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\com.hwr\com.hwr.mvc5\Controllers\AccountController.cs:804
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +99
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
```

Which point here in my code
[View a print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKJi7.png)

This behavior is similar for google, twitter and facebook. The external authentications seems to go well but the callback throw this exception.
I appreciate any suggestions offered.

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: @SLaks there you have it. I have only added the relevant part

Answer (score 2):

I can't find the source for `GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()` (in Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationManagerExtensions), but decompiling reveals (simplified):

```
await manager.AuthenticateAsync("ExternalCookie");
```

Source for `AuthenticateAsync()` is available [on CodePlex](http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin/Security/AuthenticationManager.cs), where you will find:

```
public async Task<AuthenticateResult> AuthenticateAsync(string authenticationType)
{
    return (await AuthenticateAsync(new[] { authenticationType })).SingleOrDefault();
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<AuthenticateResult>> AuthenticateAsync(string[] authenticationTypes)
{
    var results = new List<AuthenticateResult>();
    await Authenticate(authenticationTypes, AuthenticateAsyncCallback, results);
    return results;
}
```

Tracing through the `Authenticate(authenticationTypes, AuthenticateAsyncCallback, results)` call gets complicated, but ultimately the `SingleOrDefault()` error you're seeing is because your authentication configuration is resulting in multiple `AuthenticateResult` entries for the specified `authenticationType" (specifically, "ExternalCookie").

If you can post more of Startup.cs, we can probably find the exact issue.

Comment: Hello sir, thanks for your response. I Have added more  content from my `startup.cs` file, bt feel it would hv been better if you tell me the specific part to post. The file is a bit large..

Comment: Is it a copy/paste issue, or do you really have two `UseExternalSignInCookie()` calls?